# sandy land interact with the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to learn a way to make sand that interacts with movement, such as if I throw a ball at it, and it makes an impact on the sand, so I drop a cube on it.
It is in the sand when it falls I would be grateful if there were educational videos

Comment: Hi, generally we try to avoid broad questions on stackoverflow, but I am happy to help. O sill post my answer soon.

Comment: I posted my answer, hope it helps and let me know if there are any problems or you get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make and in unity, you would need a lot more processing You should create a particle system. A particle system is quite powerful. It could simulate blood or sparks when you cut metal.

To make a particle system check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPUxv-zClNA)

1. Basically, make the particle system shoot out small white/yellow/brown objects near their feet. Make it shoot out tons of objects, so it looks like it is spreading.
2. (I'm not an expert at shaders) but you could create game  objects that look like a footprint or whatever you hit into the sand. Use this script:

```
public float footprintFade;
public GameObject[] footprint;//maybe five or ten
public float halfHeight;

ParticleSystem[] ps;
void Start()
{
  ps = new ParticleSystem[footprint.Length];
  for (int i; i < footprint.Length; i++)
  {
    ps[i] = footprint.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
  }
}
int i;
DoFootPrint(Vector3 pos)
{
  footprint[i % footprint.Length].transform.position = pos;
  ps[i].Stop();
  ps[i].Play();
  i++;
}
```

When you call the function DoFootPrint(), you give it the position of where the feet should be and then it should work (as long as you have more than one footprint game object).

1. footprint should be a gameobject that looks like a footprint, with a particle system on it that looks like sand is "splashing"
2. **Make sure Looping is set to false**

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that this really will need super components for the computer.  Is it possible to make sand like making water like this example in the education video https://youtu.be/MHdDUqJHJxM

Comment: @Mix the water that that guy uses, it simulates water flowing, and it is clear. This is simulated by using shaders. This looks good because water is always flowing, so you can just repeat the same "animation". ----> Doing this with sand is possible, but it would look like it keeps **flowing**. This is bad because sand is usually stationary.

Comment: @Mix But it is possible, I will post it in a new answer

Comment: @Mix I edited my original answer, let me know if this is what you want. **REMEMBER: you must have footprint look like a footprint**, with a particle system, **in addition to the footprint.**